# DSL for hierarchical class API definitions

Tags: dsl

What do you think about syntax of my strictly typed DSL snippet below? Does it look understandable and efficient to define object graphs at a first glance?

```
   def Person(Name Name, Age Age)
       def Name
           (string First, string Last) 
               def Full = $"{First} ${Last}" 
           (string First, string Middle, string Last) 
               def Full = $"{First} {Middle[0]}. {Last}" 
       def Age
           (Date born, Date? died = null) =>
               this(Died.Year ?? Date.Today.Year - Born.Year)
           (int years) =>
               years
```

It could be used as:

```
// implicit
val person = Person(
    ("Mark", "Twain"), 
    ((1835, 11, 30), (1910, 04, 21)))

// or explicit like
val person1 = Person(
    Name("Mark", "Twain"), 
    Age((1835, 11, 30), (1910, 04, 21)))

// or fully qualified to resolve ambiguities
val person2 = Person(
    Person.Name("Mark", "Twain"), 
    Person.Age(Date(1835, 11, 30), Date(1910, 04, 21)))

Assert(true, person.Name is Person.Name)
Assert(person.Name("Mark", "Twain"), person.Name)
Assert("Mark", person.Name.First)   
Assert("Twain", person.Name.Last)
Assert("Mark Twain", person.Name.Full)
Assert(74, person.Age);
```

One more example, closures:

```
def Greeter(string Salutation)
    def Greet(string name) =>
        $"{Salutation}, {name}!" 

val greeter = Greeter("Hi")
val message = greeter.Greet("Tom")
Assert("Hi, Tom!", message)

// or like this (surprise :)
val greet = Greeter.Greet("Tom")
val greeter = Greeter("Hi")
val message = greeter(greet)              
Assert("Hi, Tom!", message)
```

Would you personally find it useful?

Comment: What is language of this dsl?